# `adb shell input` returns `Killed` response without any input registered

Tags: android, input, touch, adb

I am trying to simulate touches on my Xiaomi Mi Max 2. I tried [monkeyrunner](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html) but failed, so I am trying adb. However, each command is returned by `Killed` response and no touch/key is pressed. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: did you find a solutions for this?

Comment: @Kannan_SJD no, it's Mi Max 2 OS. You have to install another ROM if you want to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used to get this on a Xiaomi device with MIUI we used for development.

When sending `input` commands using `adb` I could not see any output and the `adb` command completed with `SIGEXIT`.

When I tried to manually issue it in an `adb shell` (on the device), I would see a `killed` output.

Solved by enabling `USB debugging (Security setting)` (Note that this is **not the standard `USB debugging`** setting, which was already enabled) in the `Developer options`. This required a number of confirmation steps, and once enabled, the `input` commands worked.

[image: setting to enable and the warning]

Answer (score -2):

You need to root your android device before executing that command. Few adb commands need root privilege

Answer (score -2):

My xiaomi max 3 works

```
PS D:\ADB Command> adb devices
List of devices attached
606704bf        device
MKJ0117A19000186        device

PS D:\ADB Command> adb -s 606704bf shell
nitrogen:/ $ input keyevent MENU
nitrogen:/ $ input keyevent MENU
nitrogen:/ $
```